# Asynchronous MediaCodec not receiving BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM in callback

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I've been implementing a video encoder which takes raw RGB frame data and encodes/muxes it into a H264 video.

Initially I was using a sync implementation with a while loop based on examples found in https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/, which worked fine.

To improve performance and readability I wanted to switch over to an asynchronous implementation, however I ran into an issue:

calling `signalEndOfInputStream` often does not set the `MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM` flag on `MediaCodec.BufferInfo`

I'm not sure when I should be sending that signal (ideally it would be in the `finalize` function, however when I tried that I never received the `BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM` flag at all.)

The encoder API looks as follows:

```kotlin
package com.app.encoder

import android.media.MediaCodec
import android.media.MediaCodecInfo
import android.media.MediaFormat
import android.media.MediaMuxer
import android.os.Environment
import android.util.Log
import java.io.File
import java.io.IOException
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.util.*

class VideoEncoder(private val width: Int, private val height: Int, private val frameRate: Int, bitRate: Int, private val fileName: String) : MediaCodec.Callback() {
    private val format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, width, height)
    private var encoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE)
    private var surface: InputSurface
    private lateinit var muxer: MediaMuxer
    private var trackIndex: Int = -1
    private var muxerStarted = false
    private val sync = Object()
    private var encoderDone = false
    private val pendingBuffers: Queue<Pair<Int, MediaCodec.BufferInfo>> = LinkedList()

    companion object {
        const val MIME_TYPE = "video/avc"
        const val IFRAME_INTERVAL = 10
        const val TAG = "VideoEncoder"
    }

    init {
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface)
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, bitRate)
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, frameRate)
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, IFRAME_INTERVAL)
        encoder.setCallback(this)
        encoder.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE)
        surface = InputSurface(encoder.createInputSurface())
        encoder.start()
    }

    /**
     * Prepares the media muxer
     */
    fun init() {
        val path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)
        val file = File(path, fileName)

        try {
            muxer = MediaMuxer(file.path, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4)
        } catch (ioe: IOException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Unable to create MediaMuxer", ioe)
        }
    }

    override fun onInputBufferAvailable(codec: MediaCodec, index: Int) {
        return // Unused
    }

    /**
     * Starts the MediaMuxer and processes the queue (if any)
     */
    override fun onOutputFormatChanged(codec: MediaCodec, format: MediaFormat) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onOutputFormatChanged")
        trackIndex = muxer.addTrack(format)
        muxer.start()
        muxerStarted = true
        Log.d(TAG, "MediaMuxer started")

        val queueIterator = pendingBuffers.iterator()
        while (queueIterator.hasNext()) {
            val p = queueIterator.next()
            mux(p.first, p.second)
            queueIterator.remove()
        }
    }

    override fun onOutputBufferAvailable(codec: MediaCodec, index: Int, info: MediaCodec.BufferInfo) {
        mux(index, info)
    }

    /**
     * Pushes encoded data into the muxer, queue's it if the muxer was not yet started
     */
    private fun mux(index: Int, info: MediaCodec.BufferInfo) {
        if (!muxerStarted) {
            pendingBuffers.add(Pair(index, info))
            return
        }

        if (info.flags and MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG != 0) {
            encoder.releaseOutputBuffer(index, false)
            return
        }

        val outputBuffer = encoder.getOutputBuffer(index)!!
        if (info.size != 0) {
            muxer.writeSampleData(trackIndex, outputBuffer, info)
        }
        encoder.releaseOutputBuffer(index, false)

        // This flag is often not set after signalEndOfInputStream(), causing a timeout in finalize()
        if ((info.flags and MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
            synchronized(sync) {
                encoderDone = true
                sync.notifyAll()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onError(codec: MediaCodec, e: MediaCodec.CodecException) {
        // TODO
        Log.d(TAG, "onError")
    }

    /**
     * Pushes a frame into the encoder using a GLES20 texture
     */
    fun addFrame(frameIndex: Int, data: ByteArray, endOfStream: Boolean) {
        if (endOfStream) {
            encoder.signalEndOfInputStream()
        }
        surface.makeCurrent()
        surface.generateSurfaceFrame(width, height, ByteBuffer.wrap(data))
        surface.setPresentationTime(frameIndex, frameRate)
        surface.swapBuffers()
        surface.releaseEGLContext()
    }

    /**
     * Awaits for the encoder to finish
     */
    fun finalize() {
        //  encoder.signalEndOfInputStream() <- I would prefer to send the signal here, but that does not work at all
        Log.d(TAG, "Finalizing")

        val waitUntil = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000
        var timedOut = false
        synchronized(sync) {
            while (!encoderDone) {
                try {
                    sync.wait(1000)
                } catch (_: InterruptedException) {
                }

                if (System.currentTimeMillis() > waitUntil) {
                    timedOut = true
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Finalized")
        release()
        if (timedOut) {
            throw RuntimeException("Timeout waiting for encoder to complete")
        }
    }

    /**
     * Releases any related objects
     */
    private fun release() {
        encoder.stop()
        encoder.release()
        surface.release()

        if (muxerStarted) {
            muxer.stop()
        }
        muxer.release()
    }
}
```

I instantiate the encoder, call `init()`, `addFrame()` all the images and finally wait for the encoder to finish using `finalize()`

In the above implementation, I have a 50/50 chance that the `BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM` flag is set, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here